# Time Dependent qUERIES

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help in addressing the below SQL request

```
EmpId   StartDate   EndDate
1   1/2/2017    12/31/9999
1   8/10/2016   1/1/2017
1   10/11/2015  8/9/2016
1   2/10/2014   10/19/2015
```

Above is table data ...

The User Provides a date range for ex: 
User Input Date   Range 10/11/2015  1/1/2017

Q1) I need to pull all the records from the table that are valid for User Input range
Q2) For each of the record i need the previous record start date --so the output should be something like this

```
EmpId   StartDate   EndDate Last Start Date
1   8/10/2016   1/1/2017    10/11/2015
1   10/11/2015  8/9/2016    2/10/2014
```

Any help is appreciated ..

Thanks 
Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should work if the start and end dates are type DATE or TIMESTAMP:

SET @rangeStart = '2015/10/11';
SET @rangeEnd = '2017/01/01';

```
SELECT
    `EmpId`,
    `StartDate`,
    `EndDate`,
    (SELECT max(`StartDate`) 
            FROM `employees` e1 
            WHERE e1.`StartDate` < e.`StartDate` 
            ORDER BY e1.`StartDate` DESC 
            LIMIT 1) as `LastStartDate`
FROM `employees` e
WHERE @rangeStart <= `StartDate` AND `EndDate` <= @rangeEnd
GROUP BY `EmpId`, `StartDate`,`EndDate`
ORDER BY `EmpId`, `StartDate` DESC,`EndDate` DESC;
```

See the [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc1947/3/2). Since you didn't specify the table name, I used employee.

It could also be done using a left join, which on large datasets may be faster:

```
SELECT
    e.`EmpId`,
    e.`StartDate`,
    e.`EndDate`,
    IFNULL(e1.`StartDate`,"") as `LastStartDate`
FROM `employees` e
LEFT JOIN `employees` e1
    ON e.`EmpId` = e1.`EmpId`
    AND e1.`StartDate` < e.`StartDate`
WHERE @rangeStart <= e.`StartDate` AND e.`EndDate` <= @rangeEnd
GROUP BY `EmpId`, `StartDate`,`EndDate`
ORDER BY `EmpId`, `StartDate` DESC,`EndDate` DESC;
```

The SQL Fiddle for both is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc1947/4/3)